# Can being hit with a tennis ball on the eye lead to pain in the ear and head?

Tags: injury

I was recently hit with a tennis ball on the left eye. Though the shot was not powerful and there was no visible injury, I did have some pain in the eye for three days. Then the pain went away and I had no problems. But I have been feeling spasms of pain on the left side of my head and in the left ear for the past twelve hours. Could this be any indication of an internal injury?

Comment: This is a question for your doctor. While the injury was sustained *during* physical exercise, it has very little to do with the exercise any more.

Comment: Agreed with Alec. My own personal (anecdotal) experience is that a blow to the eye can cause pain on that side of the face, probably something to do with nearby nerves influencing each other, but definitely see your doctor.

Comment: See an eye doctor (an ophthalmologist) sooner than later as [eye injuries](http://sanantonioeyeinstitute.com/sports-eye-injuries/) need expert care.   See the [orbital socket](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=orbits+skeleton+image&view=detailv2&&&id=AD63CE455F66BAE4A5D560A578B00E4BAF19B545&selectedIndex=4&ccid=NAV8dHim&simid=608029252148529124&thid=JN.K3YS2k5bJ40FEWNhdvwaMQ&ajaxhist=0) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks. I am just trying to find out if there is an injury at all. I realize that this question has little relevance here.

Comment: To add, I too had the experience of this as well. Ball hockey resulted in a wet tennis ball to the eye. I saw yellow for three days, and had constant headaches. I did receive eye drops from my doctor for the color, but the headaches went away on their own not long after.